# In SQLAlchemy its creating a new connection with each request until its reached 148

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, mysql-python

In my API, i am using flask, Mysql and SQLAlchemy and but also using before-request create_engine and teardown_appcontxt for session remove. But if it's by default QueuePool using connection should be 15 at server status, but it's going 148.
with each request its creating a new connection at db, while I using remove(), and one more thing I using `poolclass=NullPool` that time its working fine. If I use `Pool_size=10, max_overflow=20` etc but all these configuration not working.
code snippet is below

## can anyone limit the connection with test 2

```
from flask import Flask, session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.pool import NullPool, QueuePool


app = Flask(__name__)

# test1
engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://root:password@localhost:3306/mytestdb")
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))


# test 2 is actual problem

# engine = None
# app.session=None


# @app.before_request
# def before_request():

#     engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://root:password@localhost:3306/mytestdb")
#     app.session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))



Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__= 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    age = Column(Integer)
    city = Column(String)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
    datas = session.query(User).all()
    # datas = app.session.query(User).all()
    print([data.name for data in datas])
    return "Sucess" + str([(data.name, data.age, data.city )for data in datas])

@app.teardown_appcontext
def shutdown(exception=None):
    if session is not None:
        session.remove()
    # if app.session is not None:
    #    app.session.remove()

if __name__== "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: i hope, now you'll get the point

Answer (score 0):

this snippet solved my issue, a small change was required during create_engine time. if you are creating in before_request, also you can optimise this code

```
from flask import Flask, session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.pool import NullPool, QueuePool
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

# load_dotenv('environment/local.env')

app = Flask(__name__)


app.engine = None
app.session=None


@app.before_request
def before_request():

    if not app.engine:
        app.engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://root:password@localhost:3306/mytestdb")
        app.session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=app.engine))



Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__= 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    age = Column(Integer)
    city = Column(String)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
    datas = app.session.query(User).all()
    print([data.name for data in datas])
    return "Sucess" + str([(data.name, data.age, data.city )for data in datas])

@app.teardown_appcontext
def shutdown(exception=None):
    if app.session is not None:
       app.session.remove()

if __name__== "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```